# When encrypting ID in Java and C# using SHA-1, C# returns value with an extra 0 in front sometimes

Tags: java, c#, encryption, sha1

I have a website that connects to another external website and passes ID numbers, the page I am working on and that generates the links is written in c#, whereas the target website is written in Java and I am experiences some mismatches

I am trying to use the same approach in C# as the code in Java to encrypt the ID's, the code looks like this:

```
public static String shaHash(String input) 
throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
  if (input == null) {
    return null;
  }
  MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
  try {
    sha.update(input.getBytes("UTF8"));
    BigInteger hash = new BigInteger(1, sha.digest());
    return hash.toString(16);
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {}
  return null;
}
```

And the C# code looks like

```
StringBuilder convertedId = new StringBuilder();
            var idToByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(id);
            using (SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create())
            {
                var bytes = sha1.ComputeHash(idToByte);
                for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    convertedId.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
                }
            }
            return convertedId.ToString();
```

But the return values are different as the C# code seems like it is adding an extra 0 at the beginning:

Java: b83caf2f739209c42a8d02df0f6d4794f288703, and 
C#: 0b83caf2f739209c42a8d02df0f6d4794f288703

What  would it be the problem? I have tried to change the encoding  in the C# code for UTF8 but still doesn't work.

Any ideas guys?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I'd argue that it is the Java code that has an issue, not the C# code.  Hex encoding of bytes (which is exactly what you are doing) always has an even string length.  That is, the leading 0 is expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conversion loop takes no account of the first byte being less than 16. Try something like:

```
StringBuilder convertedId = new StringBuilder();
            var idToByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(id);
            using (SHA1 sha1 = SHA1.Create())
            {
                var bytes = sha1.ComputeHash(idToByte);
                for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 0 && bytes[i] < 16)
                        convertedId.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x1"));
                    else
                        convertedId.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
                }
            }
            return convertedId.ToString();
```

Edit: Considering Peter O's answer below, the following is a better answer:

```
         var idToByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(id);
         using (var sha1 = SHA1.Create())
         {
            var bytes = sha1.ComputeHash(idToByte);
            return new BigInteger(bytes.Reverse().ToArray()).ToString("X");
         }
```

Not that:

1) You'll need to add a reference to System.Numerics

2) BigInteger's constructor expects data in Little Endian order, hence the Reverse statement.

Comment: Thank you so much Steve, your answer solved the problem, as @Andreas pointed out in his answer, the Java code is using BigInteger which output is a base-16 number not hex-encoding of bytes (I didn't know about it). As I am not able to change that code, I adjusted mine to avoid the extra 0, and it works very well, thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 3):

The question is, do you want the extra 0 or not?

Hex output is usually done as 2 hex digits per byte, so you get an even number of digits, i.e. the leading 0 is usually what you want.

Java's `BigInteger` doesn't do that, because to it, the output is a base-16 *number*, not a hex-encoding of *bytes*.

So, rather than removing the extra 0 in C#, you should add the leading 0 in Java.

You can keep using `BigInteger` but prepend a `0` if the resulting string has an odd length (e.g. `s.length() % 2 != 0`), or use some other means of hex-encoding the `byte[]`.
See e.g. [How to convert a byte array to a hex string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9655181/5221149)

Comment: Thanks Andreas! it makes total sense however I can't change the Java code so I couldn't implement your suggestion, but you did help me to understand the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The answers given before I started this one are not ideal. Note that the Java code represents hashes as `BigInteger`s, which are essentially *numbers*, not necessarily byte arrays. `BigInteger`'s `toString(16)` prints out that number using as few base-16 digits as necessary without leading zeros. As a result, the existing answers are problematic if that number happens to be less than 2<sup>152</sup>. A better solution to match the Java code would be to strip *all* leading zeros from the base-16 string in the C# code, not just the first (unless all the bytes in the hash code are 0).